# Building OpenCL binary to use self-compiled ICD-Loader and not system-wide one

Tags: c, clang, opencl

I am currently trying to work my way into the OpenCL world step by step and am hitting a few road blocks here and there...

At the moment I am trying the following: I have downloaded and compiled the OpenCL-Headers and [ICD-Loader](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader) from Khronos. The ICD loader that is installed system-wide (in `system32\OpenCL.dll`) came from my Nvidia GPU driver installation. I am now trying to get an application to link to my self-compiled ICD loader from Khronos but have no idea what I am doing wrong. I am using a simple OpenCL examples that [lists devices](https://gist.github.com/courtneyfaulkner/7919509) and a very simple `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(listDevices C)

set(OpenCL_LIBRARY "C:/GitHub/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/install/lib/OpenCL.lib")
set(OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/GitHub/OpenCL-Headers/install/include")

find_package( OpenCL REQUIRED )

file(GLOB libsrc src/*.c)
file(GLOB libhdr include/*.h*)
set(srcFiles ${libhdr} ${libsrc})
include_directories( ${OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR} )
add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${srcFiles} )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} OpenCL::OpenCL )
```

As far as I understand, the `find_package(OpenCL)` function uses the variables defined above to find the headers and a usable OpenCL library/ICD loader. However, when compiling and running this example, the Nvidia-provided loader from `system32\OpenCL.dll` is used. I can tell because, e.g., even deleting the self-compiled loader binary doesn't change the behavior of the created executable.

Then I tried to compile it manually, which worked, but still did not achieve what I was looking for.

```
clang.exe -IC:\GitHub\OpenCL-Headers\install\include -LC:\GitHub\OpenCL-ICD-Loader\install\lib -lOpenCL  listDevices.c
```

How, if not the ways I have tried, is it possible to link against a specific ICD loader in OpenCL?

P.S.: The reason I am trying this is that I need to find a way to "install" OpenCL runtimes and actually use them in OpenCL applications without admin rights on my Windows machine. I have downloaded the Intel OpenCL CPU runtime and have patched the ICD loader to not only look for OpenCL vendors under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` but also under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. The ICD loader test [application](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader/tree/main/test/loader_test)  tells me that the patch works and that loads the vendor `INTEL` successfully. However, I cannot link other OpenCL applications against that patched loader.

Comment: The OpenCL runtime environment might not be sufficient for you to compile OpenCL programs. You need the OpenCL development environment (SDK). I suggest you find an already compiled OpenCL binary and try to run that first to see if your RE is working. I suspect you might be out of luck without admin privileges. You said your compilation worked but did not achieve what you were looking for. What were you looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have no idea whether you need the whole SDK or the runtime is sufficient to compile and run OpenCL applications, but that little P.S. was just a distraction from my main question, to be honest. I was really wondering how you manage to link the OpenCL binary against a specific ICD loader. Specifically, how can I tell it to _not_ use the ICD loader in `system32\OpenCL.dll` but the `OpenCL.dll` I compiled myself. That's still a mystery to me...